# Bottom Sheet causing parent view to shift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a bottom sheet that I toggle on and off. When I go to close out the view, I noticed the parent view shifts. I've tried adjusting the variables and couldn't find the culprit.

I have suspicion the issue is occurring on `.gesture` at the end of the bottom sheet class but I'm not sure. Is there anyway to stop the parent view from shifting when toggled?

BottomSheet

```
fileprivate enum Constants {
    static let radius: CGFloat = 16
    static let indicatorHeight: CGFloat = 6
    static let indicatorWidth: CGFloat = 60
    static let snapRatio: CGFloat = 0.25
    static let minHeightRatio: CGFloat = 0.3
}

struct BottomSheetView<Content: View>: View {
    @Binding var isOpen: Bool

    let maxHeight: CGFloat
    let minHeight: CGFloat
    let content: Content

    @GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0

    private var offset: CGFloat {
        isOpen ? 0 : maxHeight - minHeight
       
    }

    private var indicator: some View { // << toggling while open
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.radius)
            .fill(Color.secondary)
            .frame(
                width: Constants.indicatorWidth,
                height: Constants.indicatorHeight
        ).onTapGesture {
            self.isOpen.toggle()
        }
    }

    init(isOpen: Binding<Bool>, maxHeight: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.minHeight = maxHeight * Constants.minHeightRatio
        self.maxHeight = maxHeight
        self.content = content()
        self._isOpen = isOpen
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                self.indicator.padding()
                self.content
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: self.maxHeight, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
            .cornerRadius(Constants.radius)
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .bottom)
            .offset(y: max(self.offset + self.translation, 0))
            .animation(.interactiveSpring())
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.height
                }.onEnded { value in
                    let snapDistance = self.maxHeight * Constants.snapRatio
                    guard abs(value.translation.height) > snapDistance else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.isOpen = value.translation.height < 0
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
  struct TestView2: View {
   
    @State private var showMenu = false
    @State var deleteAccountSheet = false
  
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                VStack{
                   Text("click me")
                        .onTapGesture{
                            deleteAccountSheet = true
                        }
                    HStack{
                        Text( "this will move up in view" )
                            .font(.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 24))
                    }
                    Text("in the view")
                    
                }
                
            
            }
            .blur(radius: deleteAccountSheet ? 2 : 0) // blur when bottomsheet open
                GeometryReader { geometry in {
                    BottomSheetView(
                        isOpen: self.$deleteAccountSheet,
                        maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.7
                    ) {
                        Text("Give me one more click")
                            .onTapGesture{
                                print("click")
                                self.deleteAccountSheet = false
                            }
                    }
                   
                }().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                       
                }
            }
             
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VStack` containing the text was being laid out vertically with the bottom sheet. You can use a ZStack to make sure that the bottom sheet is laid out on top of the `VStack` containing text.

The height of the `VStack` containing the text and the `GeometryReader` is equal, this means the value of `geometry.size.height` is really `fullScreenHeight * 0.5 * 0.7`.

If the contents of the `NavigationView` is nested in a `ZStack` the `geometry.size.height` will be the full height of the screen in this case. Changing from `maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.7` to `maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.5 * 0.7` will give you the same sizing of the bottom sheet that you had in the example you provided. Here's an example of how to update the `View` which displays the bottom sheet to get this working:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @State private var showMenu = false
    @State var deleteAccountSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("click me")
                        .onTapGesture{
                            deleteAccountSheet = true
                        }
                    HStack{
                        Text( "this will move up in view" )
                            .font(.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 24))
                    }
                    Text("in the view")
                }
                .blur(radius: deleteAccountSheet ? 2 : 0)

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    BottomSheetView(
                        isOpen: self.$deleteAccountSheet,
                        maxHeight: geometry.size.height * 0.5 * 0.7
                    ) {
                        Text("Give me one more click")
                            .onTapGesture{
                                print("click")
                                self.deleteAccountSheet = false
                            }
                    }
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}
```